# how to tab text blocks in terminal input line

Tags: macos, terminal

```
$ I want to be able to tab from the start of one word to the next in this line, but how?
```

usually if I paste something in the input line then want to change something in the start or middle, I have to press  the left arrow for a long time, is there a faster way to do this?

Comment: What version of Mac OS X are you running? What works in Terminal from, say, Mountain Lion doesn't always work in, say, Panther or Tiger.

Answer (score 4):

Use <kbd>option ⌥</kbd>+<kbd>→</kbd> and <kbd>option ⌥</kbd>+<kbd>←</kbd>. You will be able to step by one word.

**Update:**

You can also go to start of the line using <kbd>control</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd> or to end of the line using <kbd>control</kbd>+<kbd>E</kbd>

Answer (score 0):

If you check Preferences > Settings > Keyboard > Use option as meta key, you can also use ⌥B and ⌥F (and ⌥⌫  will delete a word backward).

Terminal's default settings also affect programs like vim and nano where M-f doesn't go a word forward. I have deleted them and added this to ~/.inputrc:

```
"\e\e[C": forward-word
"\e\e[D": backward-word
```

This would also make ⌥⌦ delete a word forward:

```
"\e(": kill-word
```

Answer (score 0):

Press <kbd>ESC</kbd> then <kbd>b</kbd> or <kbd>ESC</kbd> then <kbd>f</kbd> to go back and forward respectively.